# ES6 - Checking if a class belongs to a certain class tree

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, es6-class

I have the following ES6 classes (note that the constructor and all other related methods are removed for simplicity)

```
Class Grandparent {
}


Class Parent1 extends Grandparent {
}


Class Parent2 extends Grandparent {
}


Class Self extends Parent1 {
}


Class Sibling extends Parent1 {
}
```

Then, I created the following instance

```
let myclass = new Self();
```

Is there a way that I detect if the "instance belongs to a certain class in the class tree"? Something similar to "instanceof" but for parents.  For example, the following code should help understand

```
if (myclass instanceof Self) {             // should return true

if (myclass <descendant of> Parent1) {     // should return true

if (myclass <descendant of> Grandparent) { // should return true

if (myclass <descendant of> Parent2) {     // should return false

if (myclass <descendant of> Sibling) {     // should return false
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, that’s how `instanceof` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceof`:

```js
class Grandparent {}
class Parent1 extends Grandparent {}
class Parent2 extends Grandparent {}
class Self extends Parent1 {}
class Sibling extends Parent1 {}

let myclass = new Self();

console.log(myclass instanceof Self,        "should return true");
console.log(myclass instanceof Parent1,     "should return true");
console.log(myclass instanceof Grandparent, "should return true");
console.log(myclass instanceof Parent2,     "should return false");
console.log(myclass instanceof Sibling,     "should return false");
```